# Rails 3 scope with SQL returning blank results

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following SQL statement that runs, and returns the desired result from MySQL:

```
select event_id, count(*) as num_bookmarks
from event_connections join events on events.id=event_connections.event_id
where event_connections.connectiontype = 7
```

I am trying to create a scope with this so I did the following...

```
 scope :by_bookmark_count, select("event_id, count(*) as num_bookmarks").
                            from("event_connections").
                            joins("join events on events.id=event_connections.event_id where event_connections.connectiontype = 3").
                            group("event_id")
```

When I run `Event.by_bookmark_count` from the console I get this...

```
2.1.5 :001 > Event.by_bookmark_count
  Event Load (12.4ms)  SELECT event_id, count(*) as num_bookmarks FROM event_connections join events on events.id=event_connections.event_id where event_connections.connectiontype = 7 GROUP BY event_id
 => [#<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >...
```

Note the SQL is correct, but no results are being returned. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what ended up working for me:

```
scope :by_bookmark_count, select("events.*, event_id, count(*) as num_bookmarks").
                            from("event_connections").
                            joins("join events on events.id=event_connections.event_id where event_connections.connectiontype = 3").
                            group("event_id")
```